# how can I find which genes are converted and which ones are not

Tags: r

I want to convert a set of genes which I can use the biomart to convert them

```
musGenes <- c("Hmmr", "Tlx3","STSRAAA1", "Cpeb4")
convertMouseGeneList <- function(x){
require("biomaRt")
human = useMart("ensembl", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
mouse = useMart("ensembl", dataset = "mmusculus_gene_ensembl")
genesV2 = getLDS(attributes = c("mgi_symbol"), filters = "mgi_symbol", values = x , mart = mouse, attributesL = c("hgnc_symbol"), martL = human, uniqueRows=T)
humanx <- unique(genesV2[, 2])
return(humanx)
}
```

It will return only those that are in the database but does not show which ones are not. Is there a function in biomart to not let it overlap the data ? for example in this case it should return empty for "STSRAAA1"

for example the desired output should look like this

```
Hmmr 
Tlx3
- 
Cpeb4
```

Comment: I would not place `useMart` inside a function, there is no need to define the marts with every function call.

Comment: @neilfws please tell me how would you use it. it is crazy because it makes the genes random and I cannot track anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to store the mouse gene symbols in a data frame (not a vector), with the same column name as returned by `getLDS()`. Then you can join the output using *e.g.* `merge()`.

```
library(biomaRt)
human <- useMart("ensembl", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
mouse <- useMart("ensembl", dataset = "mmusculus_gene_ensembl")

musGenes <- data.frame(MGI.symbol = c("Hmmr", "Tlx3","STSRAAA1", "Cpeb4"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

genesV2 <- getLDS(attributes = c("mgi_symbol"), 
                  filters = "mgi_symbol", 
                  values = musGenes$MGI.symbol, 
                  mart = mouse, 
                  attributesL = c("hgnc_symbol"), 
                  martL = human)

merge(musGenes, genesV2, all = TRUE)

  MGI.symbol HGNC.symbol
1      Cpeb4       CPEB4
2       Hmmr        HMMR
3   STSRAAA1        <NA>
4       Tlx3        TLX3
```